# Sublime Text 3 color highlighter does not work on windows 8.1

Tags: windows-8.1, sublimetext3, sublime-text-plugin

My Operating System is Windows 8.1, I install "Color Highlighter" plug-in for my sublime text 3 build 3065, but it does not work, when I click the color value, nothing happened. It work on my Windows 7 before

Comment: Try running it with console and see if you can read any error messaged on the console when you click on the colour value

Comment: I tried it, but the console shows nothing, and then I tried to reinstall this plug-in, it works now, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows 8.1 is not really compatible with it.
MY SOLUTION:
remove the color highlighter package and install it again

Comment: OSX 10.10 - removing and installing surprisingly worked.